# AMP extraUrlParams Custom GA Dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

I am trying to set custom variables on my AMP pages to use in GA Custom Dimensions. I have two clarifying questions I need help with

**Question 1:**
Using extraUrlParams do I use "cd1" or the variable name used in GA custom dimensions?

```
   "cd1": "<?php echo $author; ?>"
```

or

```
   "author": "<?php echo $author; ?>"
```

**Question 2:**
Do I need to set up these variables and a trigger in GTM? or does the extraUrlParams code take care of that?

Comment: Sorry I think I might've missed the GTM part from your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "cd1" it should follow this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd_
   That's if you're **NOT USING GTM for GA on AMP**.
2. How do you have GA implemented? If you implemented GA through GTM on your AMP pages, then you should use:

   {
       "vars": {
         "nameofcd1author": "Patrick",
         "nameofcd2title": "Patrick's article"
       }
     }

Then in GTM, create a AMP Variable and reference the keys in "vars", do this for all custom dimensions:
[image]

Then in your GA Tag in GTM. Configure the custom dimensions under "More settings" > "Custom Dimensions", the "Index" column is the number that refeers back to the index of the CD in GA like so:
[image]

Comment: Odd. I am using GTM for AMP, but could not get the custom variables to pass a value to GA dimension until I use extraUrlParams and cd1. Upon additional research, it appeared that only known variables like page name could be defined on AMP pages using Vars.

Comment: If your GA is implemented through GTM and you're using vars using GTM, then my instructions should allow you to pass on the custom dimensions. Can you post the code for your whole page?